# Given an array of n points of the form (x,y), the distance between two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is defined as min(abs(x1-x2), abs(y1-y2))

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

We need to find mth smallest possible distance by considering all possible pairs. I solved this problem by considering all possible pairs and maintaining a max priority queue. If the max priority queue size is less than m I push the current distance into it. Otherwise, if the size of the priority queue is greater than equal to m I check whether top of priority queue is greater than it. If so, I pop it and push this distance. The time complexity of this solution seems to be O(N^2 logn) while space complexity O(m). Can we do better than this? Especially can we do this in O(1) extra space.

Comment: It doesn't really matter for this question, but this "distance" is not a *mathematical* [distance metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a $O(n \log n)$ solution by divide and conquer, see for example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm) for Euclidean distances (shouldn't make much of a difference for this problem).

Comment: thanks a lot. It is helpful